GCC typeinfo in binary with -O3
I'm curious why gcc add typeinfo about class names even if i have enabled optimization
My flags:
-s -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-unwind-tables -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fstack-protector -fno-math-errno -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--strip-all
Should i consider adding other flag to avoid that type of gcc behavior? And also is it safe to replace those strings with 00 bytes to avoid expose of class names?



Does -fno-rtti help ?
